# How to show the output of azure synapse notebook in azure log analytics?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-log-analytics

I'm reading a table in synapse notebook from adls storage & doing some queries. After that the result of the queries needs to be logged in azure log analytics.

I've established the connection between synapse & log analytics but the result is not reflecting in log analytics.
Can someone help me out in this? Do I need to connect log analytics with storage?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for some time(10 to 15 mins) to reflect the data in the logs.

If still it's not working, follow the below approach.

As you want to log the result of the queries, store the query results in a pyspark dataframe. use `py_df=spark.sql("<query>")`.

**This is my sample data from pyspark dataframe:**

```
+-----------+------+---+
|Name       |Gender|Age|
+-----------+------+---+
|Laddu      |M     |22 |
|Rakesh     |M     |22 |
|Meg Lanning|F     |31 |
|Kobe bryant|M     |41 |
|M Starc    |M     |32 |
+-----------+------+---+
```

I have tried with the same code from this [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api?tabs=python#sample-requests) with slight modifications.

```
import json
import requests
import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

logtype ="<cutom_log_table>"
workspace_id = "<your_workspace_id>"
workspace_pkey = "<workspace_primary_key>"

def build_signature(customer_id, shared_key, date, content_length, method, content_type, resource):
    x_headers = 'x-ms-date:' + date
    string_to_hash = method + "\n" + str(content_length) + "\n" + content_type + "\n" + x_headers + "\n" + resource
    bytes_to_hash = bytes(string_to_hash, encoding="utf-8")  
    decoded_key = base64.b64decode(shared_key)
    encoded_hash = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(decoded_key, bytes_to_hash, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
    authorization = "SharedKey {}:{}".format(customer_id,encoded_hash)
    return authorization

def send_log(customer_id, shared_key, body, log_type):
    method = 'POST'
    content_type = 'application/json'
    resource = '/api/logs'
    rfc1123date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    content_length = len(body)
    signature = build_signature(customer_id, shared_key, rfc1123date, content_length, method, content_type, resource)
    uri = 'https://' + customer_id + '.ods.opinsights.azure.com' + resource + '?api-version=2016-04-01'

    headers = {
        'content-type': content_type,
        'Authorization': signature,
        'Log-Type': log_type,
        'x-ms-date': rfc1123date
    }

    response = requests.post(uri,data=body, headers=headers)
    if (response.status_code >= 200 and response.status_code <= 299):
        print('The data sent to Log Analytics Worksapce ')
    else:
        print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

#Convert pyspark to pandas dataframe
pd_df=py_df.toPandas()

#Send the data to log analytics workspace
send_log(workspace_id, workspace_pkey,pd_df.to_json(orient="records"),logtype)
```

Here, I have **converted the pyspark dataframe to pandas and later on to JSON**. You can send this JSON to the logs. Give your `custom log table name`, `workspace ID` and `Workspace primary key` in the above code.

[image]

Execute the code in synapse notebook and you can see the custom log table created in the workspace.

[image]

**Dataframe data in the log table after some time:**

[image]